# Python Twitter API program returns error code 403. Free Account

Tags: python, twitter-api-v2, twitter-api-v1

my name is John and I'm beginner with collecting data from Twitter.

Currently, I'm working on an assignment about to collect tweet about anti vaccine movements.

NOTE: I'm using the **snscrape** package.

My code is as follows:

```
pip install snscrape

import pandas as pd
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter 

scraper = sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper("#NoPlandemia")
```

SO FAR all is working. However, when the next line of code something is going bad and appears the next message.

[image]

I have tried to upgrade my account of Twitter to Basic but honestly I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

Snscrape is broken at the moment.

Source: https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape/issues/846

Comment: Now, What is the easier way to extract tweets?